# Crystal Report - Group a multiple values of parameter together in the same report

Tags: group-by, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

**Background**

Database Field `OrderHDR` has a parameter `HDR01`.

**Goal**

I'd like to group by on a parameter field.

```
3/24/2017   15273-1 W


3/28/2017   15484-1 R
3/30/2017   15503-1 R
```

**Attempts so far**

- `if ToText({ORDERHDR.HDRPASSTHRUCHAR06}) = 'R' then 'R' else 'W'`
- Report-> Select Expert-> ORDERHDR.HDR01 is equal to 'R'

These attempts only show 'R' order but I want to group the W orders separately from the R orders in the same report.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. My good reference has been [Crystal Report: How can I use a list of parameter items as a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658321/crystal-report-how-can-i-use-a-list-of-parameter-items-as-a-group)

Comment: I'm confused with the statement "Database Field OrderHDR has a parameter HDR01. It has LTL, RETAIL, WHOLESALE string value." Can you rephrase it. Do you want to say the field(i.e. column) OrderHDR in DB is linked with a crystal report parameter HDR01 (i.e. @HDR01). If so, does OrderHDR field have only 3 unique values LTL, RETAIL, WHOLESALE and do grouping on all column values ? Or you want user to specify these values in crystal reports for the parameter @HDR01 for gouping ?

Comment: @MukulVarshney  Thank you for the reply! I'd wanted to say the field(i.e. column) OrderHDR in DB is linked with a crystal report parameter HDR01 (i.e. @HDR01). And, OrderHDR field have only 3 unique values LTL, RETAIL, WHOLESALE and do grouping on all column values.

Answer (score 0):

My good reference has been the following. Basically using individual subreports for each column value and place them side-by-side.

[getting grouped records into separate view columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677791/getting-grouped-records-into-separate-view-columns)